# No files or script found for output

Tags: github, conda-build

I am playing around with building python packages with conda and cannot figure out how it works. I tried to build a package from a github source and my meta.yaml looks like this

{% set version = "0.5.0" %}

```
package:
  name: bsdiff4
  version: {{ version }}

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0

source:
  git_url: https://github.com/ilanschnell/bsdiff4.git
  git_rev: master

requirements:
  host: 
    - python >=3.8
    - conda >=4.10
    - conda-build
    - anaconda-client
  run:
    - python >=3.8
    - matplotlib >=3.3.2
    - numpy >=1.18 
    - pandas >=1.1.2 

about:
  license: GNU General Public License (GPL)
  summary: 'A package for testing the conda build mechanisms'
```

When I run "conda-build bsdiff4 --croot conda-build" I get the warning "No files or script found for output" and I do not understand why this keeps happening. Am I missing something in the meta.yaml? My build.sh is empty and I also do not want to use "script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . --no-deps --ignore-installed -vv "" if I do not have to because then I would also need a setup.py.

Full stack trace

```
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for bsdiff4
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for bsdiff4
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
BUILD START: ['bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _libgcc_mutex:          0.1-conda_forge           conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex:          4.5-1_gnu                 conda-forge
    anaconda-client:        1.7.2-py_0                conda-forge
    attrs:                  20.3.0-pyhd3deb0d_0       conda-forge
    beautifulsoup4:         4.9.3-pyhb0f4dca_0        conda-forge
    brotlipy:               0.7.0-py39h3811e60_1001   conda-forge
    bzip2:                  1.0.8-h7f98852_4          conda-forge
    ca-certificates:        2020.12.5-ha878542_0      conda-forge
    certifi:                2020.12.5-py39hf3d152e_1  conda-forge
    cffi:                   1.14.5-py39he32792d_0     conda-forge
    chardet:                4.0.0-py39hf3d152e_1      conda-forge
    clyent:                 1.2.2-py_1                conda-forge
    conda:                  4.10.0-py39hf3d152e_1     conda-forge
    conda-build:            3.21.4-py39hf3d152e_0     conda-forge
    conda-package-handling: 1.7.2-py39h38d8fee_0      conda-forge
    cryptography:           3.4.7-py39hbca0aa6_0      conda-forge
    filelock:               3.0.12-pyh9f0ad1d_0       conda-forge
    glob2:                  0.7-py_0                  conda-forge
    icu:                    68.1-h58526e2_0           conda-forge
    idna:                   2.10-pyh9f0ad1d_0         conda-forge
    importlib-metadata:     3.10.0-py39hf3d152e_0     conda-forge
    ipython_genutils:       0.2.0-py_1                conda-forge
    jinja2:                 2.11.3-pyh44b312d_0       conda-forge
    jsonschema:             3.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_3        conda-forge
    jupyter_core:           4.7.1-py39hf3d152e_0      conda-forge
    ld_impl_linux-64:       2.35.1-hea4e1c9_2         conda-forge
    libarchive:             3.5.1-h3f442fb_1          conda-forge
    libffi:                 3.3-h58526e2_2            conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:              9.3.0-h2828fa1_18         conda-forge
    libgomp:                9.3.0-h2828fa1_18         conda-forge
    libiconv:               1.16-h516909a_0           conda-forge
    liblief:                0.10.1-he1b5a44_2         conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng:           9.3.0-h6de172a_18         conda-forge
    libxml2:                2.9.10-h72842e0_3         conda-forge
    lz4-c:                  1.9.3-h9c3ff4c_0          conda-forge
    lzo:                    2.10-h516909a_1000        conda-forge
    markupsafe:             1.1.1-py39h3811e60_3      conda-forge
    nbformat:               5.1.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    ncurses:                6.2-h58526e2_4            conda-forge
    openssl:                1.1.1k-h7f98852_0         conda-forge
    patchelf:               0.11-he1b5a44_0           conda-forge
    pip:                    21.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    pkginfo:                1.7.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    psutil:                 5.8.0-py39h3811e60_1      conda-forge
    py-lief:                0.10.1-py39hfbd4741_2     conda-forge
    pycosat:                0.6.3-py39h3811e60_1006   conda-forge
    pycparser:              2.20-pyh9f0ad1d_2         conda-forge
    pyopenssl:              20.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    pyrsistent:             0.17.3-py39h3811e60_2     conda-forge
    pysocks:                1.7.1-py39hf3d152e_3      conda-forge
    python:                 3.9.2-hffdb5ce_0_cpython  conda-forge
    python-dateutil:        2.8.1-py_0                conda-forge
    python-libarchive-c:    2.9-py39hf3d152e_2        conda-forge
    python_abi:             3.9-1_cp39                conda-forge
    pytz:                   2021.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    pyyaml:                 5.4.1-py39h3811e60_0      conda-forge
    readline:               8.0-he28a2e2_2            conda-forge
    requests:               2.25.1-pyhd3deb0d_0       conda-forge
    ripgrep:                12.1.1-h516909a_1         conda-forge
    ruamel_yaml:            0.15.80-py39h3811e60_1004 conda-forge
    setuptools:             49.6.0-py39hf3d152e_3     conda-forge
    six:                    1.15.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0       conda-forge
    soupsieve:              2.0.1-py_1                conda-forge
    sqlite:                 3.35.4-h74cdb3f_0         conda-forge
    tk:                     8.6.10-h21135ba_1         conda-forge
    tqdm:                   4.60.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    traitlets:              5.0.5-py_0                conda-forge
    tzdata:                 2021a-he74cb21_0          conda-forge
    urllib3:                1.26.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    wheel:                  0.36.2-pyhd3deb0d_0       conda-forge
    xz:                     5.2.5-h516909a_1          conda-forge
    yaml:                   0.2.5-h516909a_0          conda-forge
    zipp:                   3.4.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    zlib:                   1.2.11-h516909a_1010      conda-forge
    zstd:                   1.4.9-ha95c52a_0          conda-forge

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Cloning into bare repository '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/git_cache/github.com/ilanschnell/bsdiff4.git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 64, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (64/64), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
remote: Total 666 (delta 32), reused 36 (delta 13), pack-reused 602
Receiving objects: 100% (666/666), 94.53 KiB | 2.70 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (390/390), done.
Cloning into '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work'...
done.
checkout: 'master'
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
==> /usr/bin/git log -n1 <==

commit 43591a575241b86a7558f8ea1be94ffbab49b122
Author: Ilan Schnell <ilanschnell@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 7 13:36:07 2021 -0500

    udpate changelog - next release 1.2.1

==> /usr/bin/git describe --tags --dirty <==

1.2.0-5-g43591a5

==> /usr/bin/git status <==

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

source tree in: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work
export PREFIX=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold
export BUILD_PREFIX=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/_build_env
export SRC_DIR=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work

Resource usage statistics from building bsdiff4:
   Process count: 1
   CPU time: Sys=0:00:00.0, User=-
   Memory: 3.3M
   Disk usage: 376B
   Time elapsed: 0:00:02.1


Packaging bsdiff4
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging bsdiff4
INFO conda_build.build:build(2274): Packaging bsdiff4
Packaging bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0
INFO conda_build.build:bundle_conda(1514): Packaging bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0
No files or script found for output bsdiff4
WARNING:conda_build.build:No files or script found for output bsdiff4
WARNING conda_build.build:bundle_conda(1613): No files or script found for output bsdiff4
number of files: 0
Fixing permissions
INFO :: Time taken to mark (prefix)
        0 replacements in 0 files was 0.00 seconds
TEST START: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/noarch/bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2
Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpquxhnad8/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpquxhnad8/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO conda_build.variants:_combine_spec_dictionaries(234): Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpquxhnad8/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
Nothing to test for: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/noarch/bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2
Renaming work directory '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work' to '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work_moved_bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop'
INFO:conda_build.utils:Renaming work directory '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work' to '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work_moved_bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop'
INFO conda_build.utils:shutil_move_more_retrying(2077): Renaming work directory '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work' to '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work_moved_bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop'
shutil.move(work)=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work, dest=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work_moved_bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop)
INFO:conda_build.utils:shutil.move(work)=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work, dest=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work_moved_bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop)
INFO conda_build.utils:shutil_move_more_retrying(2084): shutil.move(work)=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work, dest=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/bsdiff4_1617833720752/work_moved_bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop)
# Automatic uploading is disabled
# If you want to upload package(s) to anaconda.org later, type:


# To have conda build upload to anaconda.org automatically, use
# conda config --set anaconda_upload yes
anaconda upload \
    /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/noarch/bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2
anaconda_upload is not set.  Not uploading wheels: []

INFO :: The inputs making up the hashes for the built packages are as follows:
{
  "bsdiff4-0.5.0-py_0": {
    "recipe": {}
  }
}


####################################################################################
Resource usage summary:

Total time: 0:01:51.2
CPU usage: sys=0:00:00.0, user=0:00:00.0
Maximum memory usage observed: 3.3M
Total disk usage observed (not including envs): 376B
```

I looked at following documentation but cannot find any answer:

https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/build-scripts.html https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-build.html https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html

Comment: Hello @Greenfish, I guess I have the same issue like you. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi again, just was able to fix my issue which you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030813/doing-a-conda-build-does-not-find-any-files/69044365#69044365